Moodle. Error: Database connection failed
I'm trying to set up moodle at the very beginning after installation, this error occurs:
"Error: Database connection failed
It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running properly.
The site administrator should also check that the database details have been correctly specified in config.php
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in D:\Downloads\MoodleWindowsInstaller-latest-404\server\moodle\lib\dml\mysqli_native_moodle_database.php on line 91 "
I was looking for answers on how to solve this problem, but I didn't find it, please tell me how to solve this situation, I'm new to this.
Below is a screenshot of the error
I did it in the file config-dist.php
$CFG->dbtype    = 'mysqli';      // 'pgsql', 'mariadb', 'mysqli', 'auroramysql', 'sqlsrv' or 'oci'
that is, I installed mysql and did not change anything else

config-dist.php is an example file, the configuration needs to be in config.php - https://docs.moodle.org/404/en/Installation_quick_guide#Configure_Moodle
